# Java: Editing a Text File based on the contents of a List

Tags: java, arraylist, file-writing

This should be quite a straight forward problem. I have a large enough text file with data that looks like this

```
B38564108,EURONAV NV SHS,
B38564908,EURONAV NV CALL,
B38564958,EURONAV NV PUT,
B6S7WD106,NYXOAH S A SHS,
```

There's roughly 25 thousand lines in this file. I also have an ArrayList (labelled subStrings in the code snippet below), whereby each element in the List contains a sub string from each line of this file. The elements in the list are ordered so that the index will always be the same as the line number in the file. For example, the first 4 elements in the List are

```
{"EURONAV NV","EURONAV NV","EURONAV NV","NYXOAH S A"}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new text file with the same contents as the original text file, except having the sub string in the list element be appended with a comma. So for these 4 lines, the result would look as follows

```
B38564108,EURONAV NV, SHS,
B38564908,EURONAV NV, CALL,
B38564958,EURONAV NV, PUT,
B6S7WD106,NYXOAH S A, SHS,
```

What I've done, is store the lines in the original file as a List of strings, then tried to update each element, and write the resulting list to a new text document. This is the code currently

```
File textFile = new File("new_doc.txt");
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(originalTextFile, "UTF-8");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(textFile.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   if (subStrings.size() == lines.size()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String replacementText = subStrings.get(i).concat(",");
        lines.set(i,lines.get(i).replaceAll(subStrings.get(i), replacementText));
        bw.write(lines.get(i) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      }
      bw.close();
    }
```

The new file creates fine, however the contents are identical to the original file. There is no comma being appended to the sub String on each line.
Any pointers in the direction of what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It seems very in-efficient to loop twice. read/change/write in a one loop

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: In your code,you are not setting substrings to anything new. Substrings should be getting updated inside each iteration of the loop(PER line)

Comment: Hi @AkinOkegbile. Its the lines() list I'm trying to update inside each iteration of the loop. The subStrings() list elements should only be serving as markers to let me know where to put a comma in each element of the lines() list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want.  (Edit: no, I'm confused as to what went wrong in your code.  Check the output carefully, I think there may be something else going on.  Are you sure you are looking at the right output file?)

```
public class ListStringReplace {

   static List<String> subStrings = Arrays.asList( "EURONAV NV", "EURONAV NV", "EURONAV NV", "NYXOAH S A" );
   static List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
           "B38564108,EURONAV NV SHS",
           "B38564908,EURONAV NV CALL",
           "B38564958,EURONAV NV PUT",
           "B6S7WD106,NYXOAH S A SHS"
   );

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      substitute();
      System.out.println( "Output:\n" + lines );
   }

   private static void substitute() {
//      File textFile = new File( "new_doc.txt" );
//      List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines( originalTextFile, "UTF-8" );
//
      if( subStrings.size() == lines.size() ) {
         for( int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
//            String replacementText = subStrings.get( i ).concat( "," );
            lines.set( i, lines.get( i ).replace( subStrings.get( i ), subStrings.get( i ) + "," ) );
         }
//         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( textFile.getAbsoluteFile() );
//         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
//
//         for( int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
//            bw.write( lines.get( i ) + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) );
//         }
//         bw.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: As you say "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"

Comment: @markspace Many thanks for the response. I added a trim() to the elements of the subStrings list, and it seemed to fix the issue, so there was obviously leading or trailing spaces that I hadn't accounted for. Marking your answer as correct. Thanks again.